# VC++ Environment Variables inconsistency

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-c++

I've downloaded some projects I worked with on another machine and couldn't get them to build due to multiple errors related to missing Windows header files (excpt.h, limits.h etc.). For some reason Google suggested uninstalling, cleaning and reinstalling everything VC++, but I decided to first look at projects' include and library directories.

Apparently some of my projects used `$(VC_IncludePath)` `$(WindowsSDK_IncludePath)` and `$(VC_LibraryPath_x86)` which are undefined on my system, while my local projects use `$(VCInstallDir)include`, `$(VCInstallDir)include` and `$(VCInstallDir)lib` which work fine and adding them to project settings solves all the problems.

Any idea where the inconsistency may be coming from and which variables should I use to ensure my project builds on different machines? Thanks.

Comment: They are not Windows header files, they are compiler headers.  Stored in the vc\include subdirectory of the VS install directory.  That directory should contain over 200 files.  Users that screw up their machine by downloading beta or trial versions and not properly uninstall them tend to complain about a problem like this.

Comment: No beta's or trial's here. I guess Microsoft's inconsistency is now a user's fault?

Comment: I would suspect moving from one version of Visual Studio to another.